# Weird squares on the texture and model

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, texturing

so i was trying to render this model and well this happened on render only
[image]

After i applied a subdivision surface the model became weird as well

[image]

Does anyone have any idea on what happened :/

Comment: did you make the model or did you import it?

Comment: @Millard I downloaded from DeviantArt actually                             https://www.deviantart.com/thepwa/art/Silent-Hills-Norman-Reedus-649544122

Comment: you've probably already tried this, but try setting the objects shading to smooth again.  (sometimes, only parts of the mesh are set to smooth shading, and it can cause this weird effect.)

Comment: it might be because you need to click on the "Clear Custom Split Normals Data" in the Properties editor > Data > Geometry Data